# Confused about ios touches code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch

-(void)ccTouchesBegan...

UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

Can someone please explain in detail what exactly is going on in these two lines of code.
Thanks

Comment: Have you maybe took the time to read the documentation to see how it is described there?

Comment: sorry I realized I should have asked for more detail, that's why I asked this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
```

`touches` is a `NSSet` of `UITouch`. The code simply gets one object from `touches` and assigns it to a variable named `touch`. This is implicitly assuming that the `NSSet` hold only one element.

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
```

the above line gets the (x,y) coordinates of the touch in the coordinate system of the view that intercepted the touch. `CGPoint` is nothing more than a C struct with two float values, `x` and `y`.

So bottom line you will obtain the coordinates of the touch in the view.